# OpenGL converting between different right hand notations

Tags: opengl

I'm displaying an array of 3D points with OpenGL.  The problem is the 3D points are from a sensor where X is forward, Y is to the left, Z is up. From my understanding OpenGL has X to the right, Y up, Z out of screen. So when I use a lot of the examples of projection matrices, and cameras the points are obviously not viewed the right way, or the way that makes sense.

So to compare the two (S for sensor, O for OpenGL):

Xs == -Zo, Ys == -Xo, Zs == Yo.

Now my questions are:

1. How can I rotate the the points from S to O. I tried rotating by 90degrees around X, then Z but it doesn't appear to be working.
2. Do I even need to rotate to OpenGL convention, can I make up my own Axes (use the sensors orientation), and change the camera code? Or will some assumptions break somewhere in the graphics pipeline?

---

My implementation based on the answer below:

```
  glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(0.0f);
  model[0][1] = -1;
  model[1][2] = 1;
  model[2][0] = -1;
  // My input to the shader was a mat4 for the model matrix so need to
  // make sure the bottom right element is 1
  model[3][3] = 1;
```

The one line in the shader:

```
// Note that the above matrix is OpenGL to Sensor frame conversion
// I want Sensor to OpenGL so I need to take the inverse of the model matrix
// In the real implementation I will change the code above to 
// take inverse before sending to shader
"  gl_Position = projection * view * inverse(model) * vec4(lidar_pt.x, lidar_pt.y, lidar_pt.z, 1.0f);\n"
```

Comment: Try to do this operation in vertex shader : vec3 vertex = sensor_space_vertex.zxy*vec3(-1.0,-1.0,1.0); Also it's good to know which way you displays 3D points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert the sensor data's coordinate system into OpenGL's right-handed world-space, where the X axis points to the right, Y points up and Z points towards the user in front of the screen (i.e. "out of the screen") you can very easily come up with a 3x3 rotation matrix that will perform what you want:

Since you said that in the sensor's coordinate system X points into the screen (which is equivalent to OpenGL's -Z axis, we will map the sensor's (1, 0, 0) axis to (0, 0, -1).
And your sensor's Y axis points to the left (as you said), so that will be OpenGL's (-1, 0, 0). And likewise, the sensor's Z axis points up, so that will be OpenGL's (0, 1, 0).

With this information, we can build the rotation matrix:

```
/ 0 -1  0\
| 0  0  1|
\-1  0  0/
```

Simply multiply your sensor data vertices with this matrix before applying OpenGL's view and projection transformation.

So, when you multiply that out with a vector (Sx, Sy, Sz), you get:

```
Ox = -Sy
Oy =  Sz
Oz = -Sx
```

(where Ox/y/z is the point in OpenGL coordinates and Sx/y/z is the sensor coordinates).

Now, you can just build a transformation matrix (right-multiply against your usual model-view-projection matrix) and let a shader transform the vertices by that or you simply pre-transform the sensor vertices before uploading to OpenGL.

You *hardly ever* need *angles* in OpenGL when you know your linear algebra math.